# Acesso negado ao obter tempo de ligação do namespace

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para o `Windows Phone` e estou usando uma `namespace` que faz a ligação. O problema é que esta `namespace` diz que não tem acesso ao recurso, sendo que foi feita a declaração do mesmo no manifesto da `aplicação`.
E não é a `namespace` `Windows.Phone.Task`, pois esta não soluciona o meu problema, já que eu quero obter o tempo de ligação. Esta `namespace` que eu estou usando diz que meu acesso é negado.

Comment: O namedspace que eu estou usando é
using Windows.Phone.Notification.Management;
E o método é o seguinte:
AccessoryManager.MakePhoneCall();
Ao qual o mesmo recebe uma guid e o número, como parâmetros.

Answer (score 1):

Você está desenvolvendo para o Windows Phone 8.1?
Se sim, voce pode utilizar o namespace Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls ([MSDN Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.showphonecallui.aspx)).

Exemplo:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("Telefone", "Nome Usuario");
```

Se você estiver desenvolvendo para Windows Phone 8, use o PhoneCallTask ([MSDN Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

```
    PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
    phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "Telefone";
    phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Nome Usuario";
    phoneCallTask.Show();
```

Comment: Sim, mas porém este método eu não consigo obter o tempo de ligação, entende... Por exemplo no android eu consigo fazer uma ligação e obter o tempo de duração da ligação... Para o que eu estou fazendo é muito importante....  Tipo a tem como pegar pela o tempo que inciou e tals, mas é muita gambiarra pra uma coisa tão simples, eu queria que fosse algo mais direto pois nesta namedspace que eu passei tem o que eu quero mas não consigo utilizar, não sei porque...